# Why don't my GWAS QQPlots look the same?

Tags: r, logarithm, qq-plot, bioinformatics, gwas

I am trying to create a QQPlot of 100 log-transformed p values from a GWAS study. The idea is that taking the -log(p) will magnify the smallest p values to make them easier to see. ([reference](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Code_Sample:_Generating_QQ_Plots_in_R))

I was able to do it easily in ggplot2 in base e, but my PI wants to see it in base 10. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a built-in quantile function for base 10, so I wrote one by hand (modified from the code in [reference](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Code_Sample:_Generating_QQ_Plots_in_R)).

However, the graphs do not look exactly the same so I am wondering if I did it correctly. I don't see any reason why the base of the logarithm used should affect how the points relate to the line y = x. Does anyone know what is going on or have a better solution?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Simulate 100 p values drawn from a uniform distribution
p.values <- tibble(p = runif(100))

# QQPlot with base e
ggplot(p.values, aes(sample = -log(p))) +
  stat_qq(distribution = qexp) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Theoretical quantile function for -log10(p)
qlog10 <- function(p.values) {
  theoretical <- rank(p.values)/length(p.values)
  return(-log10(theoretical))
}

# QQplot with base 10
ggplot(p.values, aes(x = qlog10(p), y = -log10(p))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>